# CakePHP 2.1.1 > Redirection error with Basic Authentification (users/login)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, cakephp, redirect

I am trying to make a basic **user login authentification** in **CakePHP(2.1.1)** ,and it seems to work because it redirects well to users/login (in the url field) BUT when i'm on this page, Firefox says that:

*The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."*

I encounter the same kind of error with Google Chrome, so I think it's really a problem that comes from the coding of CakePHP side, especially a **redirection loop**.

**In app\Controller\AppController.php I have put :**

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

var $components = array('Auth');
}
?>
```

**In app\Controller\UsersController.php:**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array('Basic')
    )
);

public function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Not able to login');
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

}
?>
```

**in app\View\Users\login.ctp :**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('login', array('label' => 'Login : '));
echo $this->Form->input('pass', array('type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password : '));
echo $this->Form->end('Connexion');
?>
```

I really don't know where to put new code or modification to stop this redirection loop... :s

Thks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see two places in your code where redirects can happen at UserController->login() and UserController->logout(). Make sure you have Firebug installed along with [Firephp](https://getfirebug.com/downloads). Include the Firephp core [library](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Install.htm):

```
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
```

then add these lines in login() and logout():

```
$firephp->log('Login() has been fired.');
$firephp->log('Logout() has been fired.');
```

Turn on the net panel in Firebug, run your code again and if "Login() has been fired" shows up in the Firebug console output you know that it is the login() function that is doing the redirecting. Try having firephp log wherever you want to know if a script is going. You can also have it log variables to the console so you can see if things are getting set properly.

Sorry I couldn't diagnose the root of your problem, but this advice should help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

In the AppController, you should set these three values like below, it might be because of the login action redirect to itself (login page), you should set loginRedirect to other page than login page

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home');
}
```